# RoutedEventArgs.Source vs Sender

Tags: wpf, events

What is the difference between *sender* and *source* in wpf event handling?

For example, say I had an ellipse in a canvas, and clicked on the ellipse: the ellipse would be both the *sender* and the *source*.

However if the ellipse doesn't handle the event but the main window does, the event will pass through the canvas... so the canvas would be the *sender* of the event to the main window but the *source* would be the ellipse.

Do I have that right?

Answer (score 24):

The difference between the two is not often seen, as usually the `sender` and `Source` are the same. Most code written like Windows Forms will basically ignore the difference and send them along as the same reference. However, given how WPF's event routing works they represent two different concepts.

[`sender` is the object at which the event **handler** was attached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventhandler.aspx). This is the owner that raised the *handler* to begin routing the event. From MSDN:

> A difference between sender and Source is the result of the event being routed to different elements, during the traversal of the routed event through an element tree.

[image: MSDN: Event routing diagram]

[`Source` is the object where the **event** originates.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx) In the case of tunneling and bubbling, the `Source` will be one of their child elements. You can use the `OriginalSource` property to peel back any event tree encapsulation.

Comment: You provided a clear answer to an essential question of WPF development! Sounds good, hm? :)

Comment: In what scenario would sender and source not be the same?

Answer (score 9):

Bubbles!

The sender is the object that the event is being raised from, whereas source was the original element that is causing the event to be raised.

Like in this case:

```
<TabControl Name="tc1" SelectionChanged="tc1_SelectionChanged">
    <TabItem Header="1">
        <TabControl Name="tc2">
            <TabItem Header="1" />
            <TabItem Header="2" />
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2" />
</TabControl>
```

```
private void tc1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

In this case, if you change the `SelectedItem` on the Sub-`TabControl`, `sender` will equal `tc1`, `Source` will equal `tc2`.

Answer (score 5):

Sender: Current element that is handling the event

OriginalSource: original object that first raised the event

Source: object that raised event. This is usually the same as OriginalSource but when dealing with Composite Controls it can be the parent that contains the OriginalSource object.*

RoutedEvent: Provides the RoutedEvent object for the event triggered by your event handler (such as the static UIElement.MouseUpEvent object). This information is useful if you’re handling different events with the same event handler.

Handled: Allows you to halt the event bubbling or tunneling process. When a control sets the Handled property to true, the event doesn’t travel any further and isn’t raised for any other elements.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this helps :)

- **RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource** - original object that first raised the event
- **RoutedEventArgs.Source** - object that raised event.  This is usually the same as OriginalSource but when dealing with Composite Controls it can be the parent that contains the OriginalSource object.*
- **Sender** - Current element that is handling the event

> *Common cases where the source may be adjusted include content elements inside a content model for a control (the contents of a list item, for instance, will report the list item element as the Source and the actual element within the list item will be the OriginalSource).

*References*:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.source.aspx (Includes mention of Sender)