# Get Element inside Element (parent/child) WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have got a question about accessing elements inside another element.

**The situation**

```
<grid name=container>
    <grid name=menu >
       inside here is the menu
    </grid
 <button />
<grid>
```

If the button is pressed the second grid (with the menu) needs to hide. How do i access the grid element when pressing the button. This needs to be without use of the actual name of the grid because it's in a data-template and multiple objects make use of that same template, but only the actual active one needs to hide.

Comment: First put complete code. i.e. one with DataTemplate

Answer (score 1):

RoutedEventArgs class has Source, OriginalSource properties which can be used to determine the required information. In addition sender argument is also available in the event handler.

Following link explains the difference (and also answers the question), in Source, OriginalSource, and Sender. 
[RoutedEventArgs.Source vs Sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235975/routedeventargs-source-vs-sender)

RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource - original object that first raised the event

RoutedEventArgs.Source - object that raised event. This is usually the same as OriginalSource but when dealing with Composite Controls it can be the parent that contains the OriginalSource object.*

Sender - Current element that is handling the event

Comment: I actually don't get it. Right now i'm using this code                                      `Button button = (Button)e.Source as Button;
            ScatterViewItem item = (ScatterViewItem)ScatterView.ContainerFromElement(button);` The variable Item provides me the ScatterViewItem of where the button is part of. But I don't need the ScatterView Item but the grid named "Menu" inside that ScatterView Item.

Comment: peeking at your source code, you dont require parent, but sibling.
For that you have to get the parent, then you have to find the child object you are looking at.
something similar to item.FindName("menu"). 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx

                                                           
Please put complete relevant source code in case above does not solve you requirement