# Event bubbling and RoutedEventArgs Source Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I am trying to understand the RoutedEventArgs.Source property in a simple WPF application. Here is the XAML Code

```
    <Window x:Class="BubbleDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel1" Button.Click="OnOuterButtonClick">
        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Margin="5" />
        <Button x:Name="button2" Margin="5" Click="OnButton2">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1">
                <Button x:Name="innerButton1" Content="Inner Button 1" Margin="4" Padding="4" Click="OnInner1" />
                <Button x:Name="innerButton2" Content="Inner Button 2" Margin="4" Padding="4" Click="OnInner2" />
            </ListBox>
        </Button>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And here is the code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace BubbleDemo
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> messages = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = messages;
        }

        private void AddMessage(string message, object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            messages.Add(String.Format("{0}, sender: {1}; source: {2}; original source: {3}",
                message, (sender as FrameworkElement).Name,
                (e.Source as FrameworkElement).Name,
                (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).Name));  
        }

        private void OnOuterButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddMessage("outer event", sender, e);   
        }

        private void OnInner1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddMessage("inner1", sender, e);
        }

        private void OnInner2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddMessage("inner2", sender, e);

            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void OnButton2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddMessage("button2", sender, e);
            e.Source = sender;
        }
    }
}
```

When I click on InnerButton1 the click event is raised and then is executed the OnInner1 handler.
After is executed the OnButton2 Handler which sets the RoutedEventArgs.Source property with the **sender** parameter.
If you build and execute this code, you can see the output results.
When the event arrives on the OnOuterButtonClick handler, the output in the bottom ListBox should be:

*inner1, sender: innerButton1; source: innerButton1; original source: innerButton1

button2, sender: button2; source: innerButton1; original source: innerButton1

outer event, sender: stackPanel1; source: **button2**; original source: innerButton1*

but the output is this

*inner1, sender: innerButton1; source: innerButton1; original source: innerButton1

button2, sender: button2; source: innerButton1; original source: innerButton1

outer event, sender: stackPanel1; source: **innerButton1**; original source: innerButton1*

The RoutedEventArgs.Source property reassigned in the OnButton2 hander is changed but returns to reference innerButton1 within the OnOuterButtonClick handler.

Why this happens?
Thanks

Comment: Related: [RoutedEventArgs.Source vs Sender](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7235975/3357935)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really good question, and i had to look into the Source of .net to figure out *why* it is like this:

The *Source* Property looks like this:

```
public object Source
{
  get {return _source;}
  set
  {
    if (UserInitiated && InvokingHandler)
      throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.Get(SRID.RoutedEventCannotChangeWhileRouting));

    ...
  }
}
```

This execption s thrown, whenever the User tries to SET the source, while the event is Bubbling or tunneling.

I'm assuming, that the part of the .net Framework, taking care for this behavior is also catching the Exception, so you don't get aware of the problem. In fact, when trying to set the Source Property, while the event is bubbling, the Debugger shows, that is **not** changed right after setting it.

Unfortunately the source code just shows **that** Microsoft does not allow to change the Source-Property while the Event is bubbling (or tunneling), but not **why**.

If you - for whatever Reason - need to get information about the **Prior** handler that processed an event, you could create your own Extension of `RoutedEventArgs` and add another property, containing this information.

finally you can extend the `button` class, and raise your own Event, that contains the appropriate `RoutedEventArgsWithHandlerHistory` Object :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question and demanded to reflect the .net `Routing` engine. So what I found is each `UIElement` uses `RaiseEvent()` method to initiate the `RoutedEvent`. While doing so it first builds the `EventRoute`. While build `EventRoute`, it creates the list of Invoke handlers depending on the `RoutingStrategy` i.e for `Bubble` and `Tunnel` it goes up and down the `VisualTree` to which `UIElement` belongs and finds out how many Handlers are attached to the given `RoutedEvent`. As apparent, in your case for `innerButton1` and `innerButton1` there are three handlers.

Now `UIElement` got the `EventRoute` for its `RoutedEvent`, next it calls `InvokeHandlers()` on `EventRoute`. While calling the handlers in the loop, `InvokeHandler` reset the `args.Source` to the original value it has like below where it is doing it for the Bubble strategy.

```
    for (int index = 0; index < this._routeItemList.Count; ++index)
    {
      if (index >= endIndex)
      {
        object bubbleSource = this.GetBubbleSource(index, out endIndex);
        if (!reRaised)
          args.Source = bubbleSource ?? source;
      }
```

Hence before each handler call, the `Source` is reset to its original value therefore changing it inside any handler will not be passed to the next handler.