# How do I get a click event from a GridViewColumn header?

Tags: c#, wpf

I can get events from everything under the headers, but I can't get an event from clicking the headers. Here's the XAML; notice the event is for the entire ListView, so it should activate when anything is clicked:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" MouseLeftButtonUp="myListView_MouseLeftButtonUp" Margin="10">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Path"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Path}"  />
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Size"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Size}" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

And the event itself is very simple. Just show me that something has happened:

```
    private void myListView_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string output = sender.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(output);
    }
```

Clicking anywhere under the headers responds perfectly: 
"System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:0" 

Clicking the "File Path" header does nothing. Clicking the "File Size" header does nothing.

MSDN says: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745786(v=vs.100).aspx

```
<ListView x:Name='lv' Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
```

Visual Studio says there's no such thing as GridViewColumnHeader, so none of the code on MSDN works.

Comment: What is your framework version?

Comment: 4.5, it's the default setting for Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: The example you refer to seems to be valid only for .NET 4.

Comment: Actually you still can use GridViewColumnHeader.Click, even there is no hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how WPF UI events work by default. They bubble up. If somebody eats the message along the way (which is what button type controls do), the higher level controls won't get it. You can either use the Preview version of the event, or the cleaner way to do it:

```
AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ListView_OnColumnClick));
```

Comment: That seems like a step in the right direction, but I'm having trouble detecting which header I've clicked. <br>
<br>
Using the Preview version of the event says the following: <br>
"System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:0" <br>
<br>
The program crashes if I try to force it to be a GridViewColumnHeader or GridViewColumn: <br>

        private void ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            string output = (sender as GridViewColumnHeader).ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(output);
        }

crash: System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Your AddHandler event identifies the sender.ToString() as "TestApplication.MainWindow" so I'm not really sure how I can check a header from there. Trying to cast it as a GridViewColumnHeader or GridViewColumn causes the same crash type of System.NullReferenceException

Comment: You can get it at: GridViewColumnHeader columnClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader; (with the AddHandler method).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know there was such a thing as _source_ in addition to _sender_. Thanks!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235975/routedeventargs-source-vs-sender

Answer (score 2):

```
<GridViewColumn Width="150" >
                        <GridViewColumn.Header>
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click">click me</GridViewColumnHeader>
                        </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

AddHandler should be called on the ListView, like:

`myListView.AddHandler(GridViewColumnHeader.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(myListView_OnColumnClick));`

Then e.OriginalSource can be casted to GridViewColumnHeader in your myListView_OnColumnClick and you can identify your column.

Answer (score -1):

Even if a bit late, but in XAML you can do something like:

```
<!-- ListView -->
<GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
    <GridViewColumn Width="220">
        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=explorer_column_name}" Command="{Binding Path=ISortBy}" CommandParameter="{x:Static enu:SortType.Name}"/>
        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            
            //...
            
        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    //..
</GridView>
```