# Define Click event on programmatically defined WPF GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am programmatically creating a GridViewColumn in WPF as follows:

```
Dim oGVCol As GridViewColumn = New GridViewColumn

Dim oHeaderTemplate As DataTemplate
oHeaderTemplate = New DataTemplate

Dim oGridFactory As FrameworkElementFactory = New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(Grid))
oHeaderTemplate.VisualTree = oGridFactory

oGridFactory.SetValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Transparent)

oGVCol.HeaderTemplate = oHeaderTemplate
```

(I have removed irrelevant code to set the content of the grid)

What I can't figure out is how to add a "click" event for the GridViewColumnHeader itself. I can add events to the Grid and any other Controls I added through the Factory objects, no problem. But I'm stuck on how to add an event to the header itself.

If you have a solution in VB.NET, great, but C# is fine too.

One (failed) attempt:

```
AddHandler TryCast(oGVCol.Header, GridViewColumnHeader).Click, AddressOf HeaderClick
```

Sadly it turns out that I cannot cast oGVCol.Header to a GridViewColumnHeader.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527455/how-do-i-get-a-click-event-from-a-gridviewcolumn-header

Comment: Hello J. Scott Elblein - no... When a gridviewcolumn is defined in the XAML itself I have no problem defining its GridviewColumnHeader, giving it a name and handling its Click event. It's when they are dynamically added by setting a HeaderTemplate using a FrameWorkElementFactory that I have this problem.

Now I have a half baked "solution" as I can add a Preview event to the main Grid Factory:
.

Comment: oGridFactory.AddHandler(Grid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, New MouseButtonEventHandler(AddressOf PreviewHeaderMouseLeftButtonDown))

In the Event handler I can then look at the OriginalSource, go to its topmost Parent (which will be the Grid), then go to the Grid's TemplatedParent (which will be the GridViewColumnHeader) and basically add a handler for its "click" event - literally a fraction of a second before it's needed. It works. But elegant it's not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it may not be pretty, but I found a pretty decent solution to the problem.

Firstly, when I create the Grid Factory for the root element in the header's Visual Tree, I give it a name

```
oGridFactory.SetValue(Grid.NameProperty, <column name here>))
```

(Please note that the Names must have only letters, numbers and underscores so if your data contains column names that don't have those, you'll need to deal with that both here, to convert invalid names to valid ones, and below, to revert them back to their original names if necessary.... I won't detail that functionality here)

Also, I add an event handler to the Root "Grid" in the Template for the column header:

```
oGridFactory.AddHandler(Grid.SizeChangedEvent,
                        New SizeChangedEventHandler(AddressOf ColumnHeaderSizeChanged))
```

The "magic" happens in the procedure ColumnHeaderSizeChanged. This procedure is called both when the grid is Rendered the first time, but also when the user is manually resizing columns.

Signature:

```
Private Sub ColumnHeaderSizeChanged(sender As Object, e As SizeChangedEventArgs)
```

I keep a List(Of GridViewColumnHeaders) which is reset to an empty list when I need to replace the Grid with a different one. In the ColumnHeaderSizeChanged event I then do the following:

The first thing we need to do is get to the Root of the controls in the Column Header. For example, your column header may contain a TextBlock to show a column name, and icons to indicate it's been sorted up or down. That sort of thing. When the user clicks on the header they may be clicking on any of those controls, so:

```
    Dim oParent As Object
    Dim oColHeader As GridViewColumnHeader = Nothing
    Dim sColHeaderName As String = String.Empty
    Dim oGWH As Grid = Nothing

    oParent = e.OriginalSource 'This may be any of the controls in the header.
    If Not oParent Is Nothing Then
        Try
            While Not oParent.Parent Is Nothing
                'So we keep going down the Tree until we hit the Root Parent
                'which will be the main Grid created in the Grid Factory
                oParent = oParent.Parent
            End While
        Catch

        End Try
    End If

    'But at this point, if we still have a control, it will be the main Grid
    If oParent Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If TryCast(oParent, Grid) Is Nothing Then
        'what the heck is this? This SHOULD be the Grid at the root of the Visual Tree,
        'so if, for whatever reason, this is NOT a Grid, get outta here.
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

By this point we're on the main Grid, but now we need to get the GridViewColumnHeader into which this Grid has been created. So now we go to the TemplatedParent

```
        While Not oParent.TemplatedParent Is Nothing
            oParent = oParent.TemplatedParent
            oColHeader = TryCast(oParent, GridViewColumnHeader)
            If Not oColHeader Is Nothing Then
                'This procedure is called both when the Grid View is first rendered,
                'and when the user is dragging the column width.
                If Mouse.LeftButton = MouseButtonState.Pressed Then
                    'Do something appropriate to when the user is resizing the column
                Else
                    'Do something appropriate to when the grid
                    'is first Rendered or re-displayed
                End If
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
```

At this point we have the GridViewColumnHeader we need, so we can add it to the List and add a Handler for its Click event. moColHeaders is the List(Of GridViewColumnHeaders)

```
    If Not oColHeader Is Nothing Then
        If Not moColHeaders.Contains(oColHeader) Then
            oColHeader.Name = <column name here>
            moColHeaders.Add(oColHeader) 'Only need to add it once!
            AddHandler oColHeader.Click, AddressOf HeaderClick
        End If
    End If
```

Now you can code your HeaderClick procedure to handle the GridViewColumnHeader.Click event.

Signature:

```
Private Sub HeaderClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
```

Comment: Obviously you'll need to add all the code to maintain moColHeaders and to ensure it gets cleaned out properly when a view changes, but I will leave that as an exercise to the reader *cough*